# Enhance MS Dynamics CRM role based security model

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I need to enhance MS CRM Role based security model with more criteria to filter on. I.e. in addition to Business Unit access level, I need to add location access level, team access level and some other access layers based on custom entities.

I brushed through internet and MS CRM 2011 SDK but haven't found an example, how I can enhance Role based security model. Is it possible?

If it is, can you point me on example how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CRM 2011 you have more options in security model:

1. You have the concept of [teams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328485.aspx), that can have users from different BUs
2. You have [security-field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309608.aspx), to enhance the security for a field

See here [resume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309524.aspx) of all options in CRM 2011. See also this [article](http://nishantrana.wordpress.com/2011/09/24/security-roles-and-privileges-in-crm-2011-new-features/).

Another option you have is using Javascript to add more criteria:

- http://www.powerobjects.com/blog/2011/10/20/how-to-hide-a-button-on-the-ribbon-in-dynamics-crm-2011/
- http://blogs.infinite-x.net/2010/11/16/retreiving-user-roles-in-crm-2011/
- http://crmdm.blogspot.pt/2011/03/how-to-hide-show-tab-in-crm-2011-using.html
- http://crmdm.blogspot.pt/2011/02/how-to-hide-control-in-ms-crm-2011.html

Comment: +1 for links. Just remember that setting security through JavaScript is only valid in the scope of GUI. When accessing the server from the code, none of that applies. Still, it covers most of the usage of CRM so the point is definitely valid (hence the +).

Comment: Thanks for links! But is it possible to modify security model from server-side? Using teams and sharing is not enough unfortunately...

Comment: From the server you have the option of plug-in, before you execute something you cab check the roles and cancel that operation launch a exception InvalidPluginExecutionException [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334685.aspx). Through the GUI i don't know another method. I suggest JS because is a good way to apply some validation. But i agree with Konrad.

Comment: Thank you for teams concept! We will use sharing via teams to overcome the difficulties.